# C++11にstd::stouiがないのはなぜ？

Tags: c++, c++11

`C++11`で`std::stoi`が追加されていますが、`std::stoui`がありません。これはなぜですか？
`std::stoul`や`std::stoull`はあるのに…

また`unsigned int`に入れるためにはどうするのがベストでしょうか。

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715213/　でも結論は出ていないようです。

Comment: boostが利用できるならlexical_cast<unsigned int>(str1)がC++っぽいと思います。もしくはunsigned int(std::stoul(str1))でどうでしょうか。

Comment: @mossan `int`を`long`と同じとして扱うのは避けたいです…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

長文につき回答欄を使いますが回答にあらず

「なぜ」に答えられるのは [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) 規格委員会 JTC1/SC22 の委員ぐらいのもので、
オイラたち一般ユーザとしては推して知るべしに留まるわけです。
Rationale (根拠) が公開議事録に残っていればいいのですが探すのは困難です。

ここは日本語 SO なので本家の記事をちょっと意訳すると
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715213/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895583/

[c](/questions/tagged/c) 規格書 ISO/IEC 9899:1999 の 7.20 が定めている [strto系] [ato系] 標準関数は
`atof` (名前に反して `double` に変換する)
`atoi` `atol` `atoll`
`strtod` `strtof` `strtold` `strtol` `strtoll` `strtoul` `strtoull`
だけであり [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) もそれに倣ったのではないか、と推測されています。

オイラの注釈：要するに [c](/questions/tagged/c) に strtoui (unsigned int) や strtos (short) は欠けている
同様に [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) も stoui や stos が欠けている

この辺から、なんとなく
- [c](/questions/tagged/c) で要らないと判断された型への変換は [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) でも要らないと判断したとか
(疑問が「なぜ [c](/questions/tagged/c) で要らないと判断したか」に移るだけですが)
- [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) で書かれたソースコードを [c](/questions/tagged/c) に移植する際に [c](/questions/tagged/c) 側に適切な変換関数が無いものは移植困難になるから、わざと搭載しなかったとか
- [c](/questions/tagged/c) の標準関数の変換関数の挙動と厳密に同じ変換関数が欲しかったから [c](/questions/tagged/c) に無い変換は無いべきと判断したとか

まあ何の役にも立たないただの妄想ですけど

で、ではどうやって `unsigned int` `short` に値を格納すると良いか、ですが
- 昔からある `std::istringstream` でもよさそうですし
- [boost](/questions/tagged/boost) を使ってよいなら `boost::lexical_cast` でもよさそうですし
- `std` の中の実装まで追っかけて自前で類似の `stoui` `stos` を実装してもよさそうですし
（処理系を超える互換性はなくなりますが）
- 既にある `stoul` を使い `unsigned long` の値を得た後 `numeric_limits<unsigned int>` で上下限を切る wrapper を実装してもよさそうですし

っていうか [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) 的には `template<typename T> T fromstring(...)` なんてほうが自然っぽいし、
そういう選択をしなかった根拠は提示されてもよさそうな気がします。

Comment: 「なぜ」を知ることが難しいことが分かったので十分回答として価値があると思います。`boost`を使わない場合は`std::istringstream`が現実的な感じですね。テンプレートは、`std::stoi`等々の存在を無視したくない気持ちになりますのでなんとなく実装したくない…やっぱり`std::stoui`が欲しい。。

Comment: @kotatsu stringstreamでは`sto*`と同じ機能は提供できないので、同じ機能が欲しい場合は本家の回答にある[stoulを使った実装](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8715855/4955179)が良いのではないでしょうか。
ちなみに、Bjarne Stroustrupはプログラミング言語C++第4版で`sto*`関数のインターフェイスは好きではなく、stringstreamを使う方が好きだと書いています。

Comment: @alpha コメントどうもです。同じ機能が欲しいというよりは、なぜわざわざこちらに実装を書かせるのか…？という憤りの方が大きいですね(笑 `stoul`を使っても良いのですが、結局範囲チェックが必要ですよね…？ちなみに私も好き嫌いで言えば`template`を使った`stringstream`での実装の方が好みです。

Answer (score 1):

一応`std::istringstream`での実装を回答しておきます。
エラーチェックが必要ならば`std::istringstream::fail()`や`std::istringstream::eof()`を使います。

参考URL：
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/xanthus/20071011/p1

```
unsigned int StringToUInt(const std::string& input)
{
    std::istringstream iss(input);
    unsigned int output = 0;
    iss >> output;
    return output;
}
```

テンプレート版も一応…
ただ、`std::stoi`等を無視することになるため、悩ましいところです。

```
template<typename T> T StringToNumericalValue(const std::string& input)
{
    std::istringstream iss(input);
    T output = 0;
    iss >> output;
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++11で追加された`stoXX`変換関数群では、初期提案 [N1803 Simple Numeric Access](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1803.html) 時点から`stoui`は存在しなかったようです。残念ながら一連の提案文書にRationale記載もなく、「なぜ？」に答えることができません。

本当に`stoui`が必要なら、下記コードでエミュレーションできます。（[libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-5-branch/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/string_conversions.h#L50-L78)実装を参考にしました）

```
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <exception>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cerrno>

unsigned int stoui(const std::string& str, std::size_t* pos = 0, int base = 10)
{
  const char *s = str.c_str();
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  unsigned long val = std::strtoul(s, &endptr, base);
  if (endptr == s)
    throw std::invalid_argument("stoui");
  if (errno == ERANGE || std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() < val)
    throw std::out_of_range("stoui");
  if (pos)
    *pos = endptr - s;
  return static_cast<unsigned int>(val);
}
```